# window resize event for firefox using xpcom

Tags: xpcom

I am creating XPCOM Extension for firefox,I want to handle resize event for firefox Can Anyone tell me how to Register For Resize event and how to handle resize event.

Nandkumar T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an event listener for the resize event to the window that you are interested in.

Comment: how to add event Listener? where to add Event Listener? Where to handle Event? I am new in XPCOM extension Devlopment

Comment: @nandkumar Well, to start with, which window(s) are you interested in?